# Creating Map of maps with user input and searching the resultant

Tags: groovy

I am trying to create a main_map which should look like

```
[1:[gender:m, age:1, name:a]].
```

i am trying to achieve this by creating a temporary map (student_map) which looks like the below

```
[gender:m, age:1, name:a]
```

and i want to use the student_map as a value for another map (main_map) which has key value as count (for serial numbering) looking like

```
[1:[gender:m, age:1, name:a]]
```

If i run the below script and enter 3 entries the main_map shows the count incremented with 3 but the element entered last is iterated 3 times even though the value of student_map is changing, the end result i get is the last entry made in student_map iterated the times i have entered. For eg. when i run my code and enter the values through command prompt.

```
1st Entry(through command prompt)
name=a
age=1
gender=m

2nd Entry 
name=b
age=2
gender=m

3rd entry
name=c
age=3
gender=m
```

expected output

```
[1:[gender:m, age:1, name:a],2:[gender:m, age:2, name:b],3:[gender:m,    age:3, name:c]]
```

Output i am getting

```
[1:[gender:m, age:3, name:c], 2:[gender:m, age:3, name:c], 3:[gender:m, age:3, name:c]]
```

NOTE:I am not able to search this map for a particular value with the below one line piece of code

```
def result=main_map.find{it.value.name == 'a'} \\This is present in both pieces of code below \\
```

I have pasted two pieces of code below (Both work but not as expected)

Code 1 - This gives me the unexpected output

```
def answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'

def student_map = new HashMap()

//print student_map.getClass()
def main_map = [:]
//print main_map.getClass()
def count=0
while (answer=='Y' || answer=='y') { 

         count++
         def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
         def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
         def gender=System.console().readLine 'What is your gender M/F\n'

         student_map.put('name',"${name}")
         student_map.put('age',"${age}")
         student_map.put('gender',"${gender}")

        print student_map

         main_map.put("${count}","${student_map}")

         print main_map 
         answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 

         }

print main_map  

def name='a'
def result=main_map.find{it.value.name == 'a'}
```

Code 2 - This gives me the expected output but with no luck in searching for a value

```
def answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'

def student_map = new HashMap()

//print student_map.getClass()
def main_map = [:]
//print main_map.getClass()
def count=0
while (answer=='Y' || answer=='y') { 

         count++
         def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
         def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
         def gender=System.console().readLine 'What is your gender M/F\n'

         student_map=[name:(name),age:(age),gender:(gender)]            
        print student_map

         main_map.put("${count}","${student_map}")

         print main_map 
         answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 

         }

print main_map  

def name='a'
def result=main_map.find{it.value.name == 'a'}
```

Appreciate any help i can get

Thanks for the reply vahidreza. I have corrected that part and now was stuck with putting that map into a file.
I am having problems with line below line of my script. I am not able to insert both the key and value although i can insert either key or value

Working

```
  main_map.each {k, v -> writer.print(k)} 
  o/p from file
  12 (i entered two records so the count incremented twice and hence 1 and 2)
```

Not Working

```
  main_map.each {k, v -> writer.print(k,v)}
```

Full Script

```
  def answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'

  def student_map = new HashMap()

  //print student_map.getClass()
  def main_map = [:]
  //print main_map.getClass()
  def count=0
   while (answer=='Y' || answer=='y') { 

               count++

               def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
               def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
               def sex=System.console().readLine 'What is your sex M/F\n'

               student_map=[name:(name),age:(age),sex:(sex)]            

               //print student_map

               main_map.put((count),(student_map))

               //print main_map 
               answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 

               }

  File f = new File ("C:/Apoorv/groovy-2.0.8/Groovy_programs/students.txt")
  writer = new PrintWriter(f)

  main_map.each {k, v -> writer.print(k,v)} 

  writer.close()
  def student_name = System.console().readLine 'Name to search ?\n'
  def result = main_map.find { it.value.name == "${student_name}" } 
  print result
```

Thanks for the reply. I had fixed the part that was not working/working incorrectly. Now i am having some problems with putting the data in a file and storing it. As mentioned earlier i am able to store either key or value of a particular record in a file but i am not able to insert the whole record in the file.

Update ## My code is working fine and is doing what i intend it to do but there is weird problem with the sorting ###

Below is my code for your reference

Code#

```
  def answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'

  def student_map = new HashMap()
  //print student_map.getClass()
  def main_map = [:]
  //print main_map.getClass()
  def count=0
   while (answer=='Y' || answer=='y') { 

               count++

               def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
               def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
               def sex=System.console().readLine 'What is your sex M/F\n'

               student_map=[name:(name),age:(age),sex:(sex)]            

               //print student_map

               main_map.put((count),(student_map))

               //print main_map 
               answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 

               }

  print main_map.values().sort { a, b -> a.age <=> b.age}             

  File f = new File ("C:/Apoorv/groovy-2.0.8/Groovy_programs/students.txt") // Writing in file student.txt //
  writer = new PrintWriter(f)
  writer.print main_map
  writer.close()

  print main_map
  def student_name = System.console().readLine 'Name to search ?\n'
  def result = main_map.find { it.value.name == "${student_name}" } 
  print result
```

i want to sort the values based on the values of the map student_map. 
i am using the below line to achieve it

```
print main_map.values().sort { a, b -> a.age <=> b.age}
```

This works but does not work for values with 4 digits. Consider the below examples.

I/p given through the command prompt

```
Do you want to add a student Y/N
What is your name
apoorv
What is your age
100
What is your sex M/F
m
Do you want to continueY/N
y
What is your name
kaandi
What is your age
21
What is your sex M/F
m
Do you want to continueY/N
y
What is your name
manjushree
What is your age
19
What is your sex M/F
f
Do you want to continueY/N
n
```

Output

```
[[name:apoorv, age:100, sex:m], [name:manjushree, age:19, sex:f],   [name:kaandi, age:21, sex:m]]
```

As you can see that the second and third entry got sorted but not the first one. I am not able to understand this behavior of the sort function.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Why put string value of student_map in `main_map.put("${count}","${student_map}")` and don't use it originally as Map like this : `main_map.put("${count}",student_map)`?

Comment: you are aware, that printing in groovy is no way of serialization? the bare minimum to deal with this is using `inspect` (and i would not go that route either).  serialize with json/xml/yaml/edn/...  also don't mix your reading/writing and the need for a map.  just build a list of students and use tools like `groupBy` to build up your datamodel.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's output looks good to me... am I missing something?

#### Groovy (run.groovy)

```
def answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to add a student Y/N\n'
def student_map = new HashMap()
def main_map = [:]
def count=0
while (answer=='Y' || answer=='y') { 
   count++
   def name=System.console().readLine 'What is your name\n'
   def age=System.console().readLine 'What is your age\n'
   def sex=System.console().readLine 'What is your sex M/F\n'
   student_map=[name:(name),age:(age),sex:(sex)]
   main_map.put((count),(student_map))
   answer=System.console().readLine 'Do you want to continueY/N\n' 
}
println main_map
```

#### Command

```
C:\tmp>groovy run.groovy
Do you want to add a student Y/N
y
What is your name
a
What is your age
1
What is your sex M/F
m
Do you want to continueY/N
y
What is your name
b
What is your age
2
What is your sex M/F
m
Do you want to continueY/N
y
What is your name
c
What is your age
3
What is your sex M/F
f
Do you want to continueY/N
n
[1:[name:a, age:1, sex:m], 2:[name:b, age:2, sex:m], 3:[name:c, age:3, sex:f]]
```

The output looks correct, right? Are you running the code inside your ide?